# Python module PyMySQL not taking arguments

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu-14.04, pymysql

I wrote a python script that communicate with MySQL server on OSX 10.10, it runs fine Mac until I put it on an VPS running Ubuntu 14.04

The problem mainly lies on the pyMySQL module. :I can't even run their example script on the git page [here](https://github.com/PyMySQL/PyMySQL)

for running the following code:

```
import pymysql.cursors

# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost',
                         user='user',
                         password='passwd',
                         db='db',
                         charset='utf8mb4',
                         cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
try:
    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
        # Create a new record
        sql = "INSERT INTO `users` (`email`, `password`) VALUES (%s, %s)"
        cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org', 'very-secret'))

    # connection is not autocommit by default. So you must commit to save
    # your changes.
    connection.commit()

    with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    # Read a single record
    sql = "SELECT `id`, `password` FROM `users` WHERE `email`=%s"
    cursor.execute(sql, ('webmaster@python.org',))
    result = cursor.fetchone()
    print(result)
finally:
    connection.close()
```

The result is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "1.py", line 9, in <module>
cursorclass=pymysql.cursors.DictCursor)
File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/pymysql/__init__.py", line 93, in Connect
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'password'
```

Environment: 
Ubuntu 14.04 x86_64 
Python 2.7.10
PyMySQL 0.6.7
Mac is running the above script fine but not the ubuntu. 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't do much checking on the error message. Instead I uninstall all the packages on the unbuntu server and follow the package list on the Mac to install them again one by one to the same version. Amazingly, the problem is solved. Unfortunately I can't tell which module is causing the problem

You might want to give it a try if you don't want to spend much time on updating modules one by one.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that this is a ubuntu problem, which is solved if you install the latest pypi version.

I removed the package from ubuntu in dist-packages and installed it in site-packages:

```
sudo apt-get purge python3-pymysql
sudo pip3 install --upgrade pymysql
```

You don't (really) want to do this, especially on a server. Alternatively you use a virtualenv:

```
virtualenv -p python3.4 venv3
source venv3/bin/activate
pip3 install --update pip
pip3 install --update pymysql
```

You need to learn a bit more about virtualenv's to use them, but the idea is that you have a complete and separate python3.4 environment installed in `venv3` which you activate with `source venv3/bin/activate`. This way it is harder to break your ubuntu (which heavily depends on a working python). Moreover, you can install different versions of packages in different virtualenv's. Also, when debugging, you can add print-statements to python-code in the site-packages folder of the virtualenv, without risking breaking your system severely. This is great, as many good python libraries have poor error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

Faced this error with Python:3.6, PyMySQL3:0.5.
solution: change 'password' parameter to 'passwd'

Below is the parameters list with default values
host="localhost", user=None, passwd="", db=None, port=3306, unix_socket=None, charset='', sql_mode=None, read_default_file=None, conv=decoders, use_unicode=None, client_flag=0, cursorclass=Cursor, init_command=None, connect_timeout=None, ssl=None, read_default_group=None, compress=None, named_pipe=None